# Merge [pyunit] with [python-unittest]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags for [pyunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyunit) (*146 questions*) and [python-unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-unittest) (*1,283 questions*) should be merged, as both names refer to the same testing library.

[Python's `unittest` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html):

> The Python unit testing framework, **sometimes referred to as
>   “PyUnit,”** is a Python language version of JUnit, by Kent Beck and
>   Erich Gamma.

[Python 3 How to: Write Unit tests](https://syndbg.wordpress.com/2014/04/20/python-3-how-to-write-unit-tests-unittest-pytest-nose/):

> In the following blog post I’ll cover the following frameworks for
>   unit testing.
>
> 1) **PyUnit, also known as unittest in the Python modules.**

I propose using [python-unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-unittest) as the master tag, as it is the more commonly used tag.

Comment: [*Update: Unless you're stuck in the year 2000, PyUnit is in your Python standard library as module unittest.*](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/). Yes, pyunit should be a synonym for python-unittest

Comment: `self.assertEqual([pyunit], [python-unittest])`

Comment: @alexwlchan -- what's does `python - unittest` evaluate to?

Comment: @mgilson An exception