# Rename [py.test] to [pytest]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

As mentioned in `pytest`'s [FAQ](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-can-i-use-both-pytest-and-py-test-commands):

> `pytest` used to be part of the `py` package, which provided several developer utilities, all starting with `py.<TAB>`, thus providing nice TAB-completion. If you install `pip install pycmd` you get these tools from a separate package. Once pytest became a separate package, the `py.test` name was retained due to avoid a naming conflict with another tool. This conflict was eventually resolved, and the `pytest` command was therefore introduced. In future versions of `pytest`, we may deprecate and later remove the `py.test` command to avoid perpetuating the confusion.

May I suggest to rename the [py.test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/py.test) tag to [pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytest)? The latter is the official package/distribution/cli entrypoint name for several years now (at least since the release of 3.0 in 2016, with the remaining usages of `py.test` cleaned up in code and docs) so there should be no need to stick with the old name.

Comment: I'm actually surprised it hasn't already been done ...

Comment: Related: [Merge \[pyunit\] with \[python-unittest\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358953/3357935)

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a good idea. If you take a look at the description for the [py.test](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/py.test/info) tag there is a mixture of pytest and py.test.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/py.test/info

> pytest: simple powerful no-boilerplate testing with Python Please use the `python` tag for questions tagged with `py.test`. Please also consider adding the `testing` tag as well, in case someone learning about testing in general might benefit from the question.
>
> py.test is a mature, fully featured testing tool that simplifies the testing experience, which ...

When following the hyperlink within the py.test description it takes you to the pytest website which does name the project pytest.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/

> pytest: helps you write better programs
>
> The pytest framework makes it easy to write small tests, yet scales to support complex functional testing for applications and libraries.

Bringing the description and tag name into line with each other seems trivial and may help remove any possible confusion.

Comment: Thanks! I have also refurbished the tag info, rewording and cleaning up the outdated/broken links. Should be reviewed first, though.